# Using exception for communication

Tags: java, exception, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have heard that one should not use exception for communication.
I have a scenario that I would like to discuss. 
We have a rest controller that invokes a service that is responsible for fetching a product from the database. Currently if product can't be found we will get an exception (checked exception) productNotFoundException.
This exception goes all the way to the controller. In the controller we have a controller exception handler (controller advice)  that takes care of the exceptions and returns 404.

I was told that if they are run on different threads then the whole application would crash and it would be better to deal with the exception directly. Currently a lot of methods are being called and all have throws prodNotfoundex.

Can some one explain why it would crash. My project is a spring boot project.

I was told to return an empty response to the controller instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how it would crash your application, if you handle/catch the exception properly.

Regarding exceptions, it should be seen as an *exceptional* state -- that is not in the normal flow of actions. Eg. the `FileNotFoundException` is exceptional, because you wanted to open the file, but it's not there. You expected it to be there, but it wasn't.

If you search for a product, you don't expect it to be there in the general sense of "expecting to find a loaf in the grocery store". You searched for a bunch of keywords, and the search resulted an empty response/zero matches. It is not exceptional in your business logic.

On the other hand, when you click "order" on a product (say on the product page), and *then* the product is not found, it is "exceptional". You expected a product you found 2 minutes ago to be there, but it isn't any more.

Some links on Java Exception handling costs:

- http://java-performance.info/throwing-an-exception-in-java-is-very-slow/
- [Is it expensive to use try-catch blocks even if an exception is never thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451777/is-it-expensive-to-use-try-catch-blocks-even-if-an-exception-is-never-thrown)
- [How expensive are Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567579/how-expensive-are-exceptions)
- [How slow are Java exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions)

Decide it for yourself.

Comment: "expecting to find a loaf in the grocery store" Would that be an exception if you cant find one

Comment: That's a tricky question. I enter the store expecting them to have one (eg. because they advertise themselves as "always with fresh bread", so I expect bread to be on stock).